# creating a page break command

Tags: page-breaking, page-numbering

I need a command to create a page break, and here's my attempt:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\blankpage{%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage\mbox{}\clearpage}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\blankpage

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

However, I don't want the page number to appear in the page break. The command `\thispagestyle{empty}` doesn't work, how can I do it?

Comment: There alread is a command called `\pagebreak` which you don't want to use. There is also `cleardoublepage.` and the `emptypage` package. There is also `report`  and `book` which introduce those pages automatically. You most likely want to go with the last thing of changng the class.

Comment: You are setting the pagestyle to plain on this page, clear to the next (which you want to be empty) and clear to the next once more. If you want that page empty, why are you setting this empty instead?

Comment: I am not sure I am following you. I want the blank page to be empty.

Comment: I understand. You want that page to be empty. But you are setting this page to be empty, which is the first. Look at your own example and output. `\newcommand\blankpage{\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\mbox{}\clearpage}`

Comment: Ok, so I just need to move `thispagestyle{empty}` before `\clearpage`? Is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: Sorry, I meant, just moving `\clearpage` AFTER `\thispagestyle{empty}`.

Comment: Yes, try it out.

Answer (score 2):

You need the following ordering within something like `\insertblankpage`:

```
\newcommand{\insertblankpage}{%
  \clearpage% Flush pending page content
  \thispagestyle{empty}% Set page style to be 'empty' (no header/footer)
  \mbox{}% Some some (blank) content on the page
  \clearpage}% Flash page content
```

That is, you need to (in order)

1. `\clearpage` - flush all pending page content;
2. `\thispagestyle{empty}` - set the page style to be `empty` and therefore avoid any headers/footers from being displayed;
3. `\mbox{}` - set some (invisible) content on the page; and
4. `\clearpage` - flush all pending page content again.

Calls to (2) and (3) can be swapped as they both pertain to different (invisible) content on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Moving `\clearpage` up in the definition will fix the problem. Try this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\blankpage{%
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\mbox{}\clearpage}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\blankpage

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```