# create a blank page

Tags: blank-page

I want to create a blank page. I looked up on the web and I tried the code:

```
\newcommand\blankpage{% comando pagina vuota
    \newpage
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage
}
```

but it doesn't work. I have also tried this:

```
\newcommand*\NewPage{\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage}
```

I am writing in the article mode. Should I use a package?

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't work? the `\blankpage` command  you defined will force a blank page without increasing the page counter

Comment: Related: [creating a page break command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325909/5764)

Comment: @Werner Why is it that inserting a blank page such an intricate process in LaTeX ? This is a silly thing in GUI systems. I thought `\newpage \pagestyle{empty} \clearpage` should do the job until I hit the roadblock and came searching here!!

Comment: @vrgovinda: (La)TeX is not a GUI system; those tend to perform a lot of background legwork automatically, together with assumptions about what the user wants (to see). This is commonly referred to as WYSIWYG, which (La)TeX is not.

Comment: @Werner: I am a proud (Xe)LaTeX user for the last 10 years [created my dissertation thesis, teaching assignments and 3 books using (Xe)LaTeX. But for me creating a blank page was akin to creating a new line. This should have a much simpler way. That's what I wanted to convey.

Answer (score 11):

A blank page without header, footer or page number and without increasing the page number:

```
\shipout\null
```

The page number can be increased by one via:

```
\stepcounter{page}
```

The macro of the question has a flaw in `twocolumn` mode, because `\newpage` does not end a page, but the current column. `\clearpage` is the better choice. It also prevents that floating objects are going to the page:

```
\newcommand\blankpage{% comando pagina vuota
    \clearpage
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \clearpage
}
```

If package `hyperref` is used, then the previous page and the empty page share the same page number in violation of unique page anchors. The page anchor can be turned off for the empty page:

```
\newcommand\blankpage{% comando pagina vuota
    \clearpage
    \begingroup
      \null
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
      \hypersetup{pageanchor=false}%
      \clearpage
    \endgroup
}
```

Comment: I think that the suggestion of using `\shipout\null`, although correct in principle, could be confusing to inexperienced users: due to TeX’s asynchronous output mechanism, in practice you need to say something like `\clearpage\shipout\null`.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Maybe, or `\usepackage{afterpage}...\afterpage{\shipout\null}`. Unhappily, the question does not describe the context and purpose of the empty page.

Comment: If I want the blank page to not increase the number of total pages detected by `zref` using `\ztotpages`, should I remove the second `\clearpage` before `\endgroup`?