# Margins on blank pages, report

Tags: margins, blank-page, binding

I'm having problems with the margins and "sidedness" of blank pages in my document. The page following a blank page has the same "sidedness" as the blank page, when it should switch on every page. For example, the title page has a larger left inner margin (for binding), the following blank page has a larger right inner margin, and the page following that SHOULD have a larger left inner margin (but it also has a larger right inner margin).

Here's a MWE with important part of the preamble and other relevant parts.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

%% LOAD PACKAGES %%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,german]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}       % page margins ([showframe] for visble margins)
\usepackage[english,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{afterpage}                                  % command for blank pages


%% FORMATTING %%
\geometry{                      % format page margins
    left=2.6cm,
    right=2.6cm,
    top=2cm,
    bottom=2cm,
    includeheadfoot,
    showframe,
    bindingoffset=.5cm              %%% remove for digital copy
}

\newcommand{\blankpage}{                        % for blank pages           https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331064/create-a-blank-page
    \null
    \clearpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \hypersetup{pageanchor=false}%
    \newpage
}



%% START DOCUMENT %%

\begin{document}

Here's my title page
    \newpage
    {\blankpage\clearpage}                                  %%%
Here's my dediction page
    \afterpage{\blankpage\clearpage}            %%%
    \newpage 
    \thispagestyle{plain}
Here's my table of contents
    \newpage 
    \thispagestyle{plain}
Here's my wonderful quote
    \afterpage{\blankpage\clearpage}            %%%
    
    % ...and so on
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: why using `\afterpage` here? You have specified the left and right margins with geometry to be the same on odd or even pages so ther isn't much difference between od an even, also `\addtocounter{page}{-1}` looks wrong and will account for your main issue as that will force two adjacent pages to have the same number (even if not printed) so have the same page settings.

Comment: There is no difference between odd and even pages. Left and right pages should differ in their bindingoffset by .5cm.

Comment: I have removed `\addtocounter{page}{-1}` and it helps, but it still doesn't resolve it completely.

Comment: Without `\afterpage` the `\blankpage` command sometimes does show up in the correct spot.

Comment: I'd be grateful for clarification on the difference between `\clearpage`, `\newpage`, and the use of `\ `.

Comment: afterpage can't be the right thing here (I wrote that package and I'd never use it like that) `\clearpage` is `\newpage` but forces out any pending floats (figure, tables, ...) so they do not go past that point, so there is no differenc in the code shown that has no floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this syntax to force creating empty pages:

```
\newpage
\
\newpage
```

or put it a command as such:

```
\def\blankpage{%
\newpage
\
\newpage}
```

Then call it with `\blankpage{}`

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly.