# How to have Appendix A continue by Appendix B

Tags: appendices

I want to make Appendix A continue by Appendix B. This is the command I used:

```
\appendix
\include{appendixA} \label{appendixprocedure}
\newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\include{appendixB} \label{appendixlinearization}
\newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
```

But I got both in the naming Appendix A.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can reproduce this problem is by including the `\appendix` command inside your `appendixA.tex` and `appendixB.tex`. Here's an example that replicates this (even though it's an `article` without `\include`s, the principle remains the same):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}

\appendix
\section{An appendix}

\appendix
\section{Another appendix}

\end{document}
```

If this is what you're doing, you're doing it wrong. `\appendix` resets appendix-specific counters (which may depend on your document class). Here's what `\appendix` does in [`book`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co) and [`report`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls?view=co) (comments added):

```
\newcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}% <--- Reset chapter counter
  \setcounter{section}{0}% <--- Reset section counter
  \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}}
```

[`article`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co) does something similar, only one level down:

```
\newcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}% <--- Reset section counter
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}% <--- Reset subsection counter
  \gdef\thesection{\@Alph\c@section}}
```

It is obvious that `\appendix` reset the main appendix counters, so including it as part of every appendix unit is incorrect. Only use it once to demarcate the end of your regular chapters and the start of the appendices.

In conclusion, remove `\appendix` from your `appendixA.tex` and `appendixB.tex`.

<sub>Some things to note in your code:</sub>

- Your `\label`s might not reference the correct location within your document, as it is only called at the end of every appendix.
- `\newpage` does not take an argument, so don't use `\newpage{..}`.
- If you want a blank (no header/footer) page between your appendices, consider reading [Really blank pages between chapters](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-reallyblank.html) or [creating a page break command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325909/5764).

Answer (score 1):

> Use the commands `chapter`, `section` (depending on your document class) and so on as in the rest of the
>   document.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}

\section{Secound Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}

\appendix
\section{First Appendix}
\section{Secound Appendix}
\section{Third Appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the `\appendix` should start the Appendix-part, so you can just start `\section`s after the appendix-command.